# How to determine if a permission exists only once inside a list in mvc razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a list like below

```
public List<DocumentsWithSharedWithMeFromDepartmentsDto> DocumentsSharedWithMeFromDepartments { get; set; }
```

inside of that list I have permissions list

```
public List<PermissionsListDto> UserPermissions { get; set; }
```

So each DocumentsSharedWithMeFromDepartments item may have multiple different permissions from different departments. My question is when I bind this model to view I want to conditionally show a user some buttons according to this permissions like so.

```
foreach (var permission in Permissions)                                                                       
{
   if (permission.Name == PermissionNames.Pages_Documents_Edit) // string constant                                                                               
   {
    //Edit Button Here
   }
   if (permission.Name == PermissionNames.Pages_Documents_Delete)                                                                                
   {
    //Delete Button Here
   }
   if (permission.Name == PermissionNames.Pages_Documents_Update)                                                                                
   {
    //Update Button Here
   }
}
```

Some of the buttons are repeating just because when a user is a member of different two departments and those departments have both same "edit" or "delete" permissions. I should be able to show any of the button just once if that permission granted to that user from whichever department.

What I tried so far :

```
if (document.Where(x => x.Permissions.Any(y => y.Name == PermissionNames.Pages_Documents_Edit)) != null)
 {
    //Button here                                                                
 }
```

My structure might be wrong. I would really appreciate if anyone put me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing

Comment: A `.Where()` will not be `null`, just empty. You probably want just `if (document.Permissions.Any(y => y.Name == PermissionNames.Pages_Documents_Edit) { // add button }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah, except that `document` is collection itself, so first we should flatten permissions

Comment: @tchelidze, Is it? (I assume OP is looping through the collections, especially since the collection property is named `DocumentsSharedWithMeFromDepartments`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Seems like this, may he assigned `DocumentsSharedWithMeFromDepartments` to `document` for sake of space.

Comment: @tchelidze I think OP wants the buttons to edit, update or delete each document (just one set of buttons for the whole collection would not make much sense)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds logical

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm looping through the collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than checking whether there are multiple permissions within your loop, you could restrict the permissions list so that it only contains one of each permission. For instance:

```
foreach (var permission in Permissions.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(p => p.First()).ToList())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to me. I will try this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing `Where` clause result (`IEnumerable`) to `null` evaluates to `true`.

Try following

```
@foreach(var document in Model.DocumentsSharedWithMeFromDepartments)
{
   //document details here
   if (document.Permissions.Any(it => it.Name == PermissionNames.Pages_Documents_Edit))  
   {
    //Button here                                                                
  }
}
```